# Reverse engineering phase shift and numerical damping

Tags: ode, computational-physics, linear-solver, integration, error-estimation

I've been trying to validate the physics behind a particle system framework, but I'm having some difficulties.
A particle system is a set of lumped masses connected by spring-damper elements. Linear forces are assumed.
By setting the damping to 0, fixing one particle at a position of 0, and letting the other freely oscillate an undamped simple harmonic oscillator can be simulated. The exact solution over time is represented by the green line in the figure.
The numerical integration scheme used is implicit Euler, which to my knowledge results in numerical damping and a phase shift.
In the figure, a typical simulation result can be seen in orange, and the effect of using this first-order method is clearly visible. I would like to find the decay rate and increasing phase shift over time if that is possible, but I haven't been able to find an analytical solution. I would want to use this to reverse engineer the curve to the exact solution. I would like to have this, because I want to include damping, undo this decay rate and phase shift and check how well the simulation matches the exact solution.

I hope you can help me out, and thank you either way.

[image]

Comment: Do a Fourier transform over a time window at the end. The Fourier transform will have a single dominant frequency for both the exact and the approximate solution. You get the amplitude of the curve by looking at the magnitude of the Fourier transform's dominant frequency, and the phase shift from the complex angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an undampened harmonic oscillator $\ddot x+w^2x=0$ you can set the velocity component to $\dot x=wy$ and then $z=x+iy$ to get
$$
\dot z=wy-iwx=-iwz.
$$
The implicit Euler method can now be exactly and compactly written as $z_{n+1}=(1+iwh)^{-1}z_n$, and the iteration solved as
$$
z_n=(1+iwh)^{-n}z_0=e^{-n(iwh+\frac12(wh)^2-\frac{i}3(wh)^3+...)}z_0
=e^{-iwt_n(1-\frac13(wh)^2)}e^{-\frac12w^2ht_n}u_0
$$
This formula contains both effects, the frequency reduction to $w(1-\frac13w^2h^2)$ and the exponential amplitude decay at rate $-\frac12w^2h$.

While these approximations are conform with the general idea that the implicit step is shorter than the exact step, it is in conflict with the plot which shows a reduced wave length and thus an increased frequency.